# Validating a form in Masonite

Tags: python, masonite

I'm trying to use the validator engine in Masonite to validate form data. Each validator works by itself, but when I try and chain a bunch of validators together it doesn't work.

```py
       errors = request.validate(
            validate.when(
                validate.exists(['title', 'body', 'lat', 'lon'])
            ).then(
                validate.string(['title', 'body']),
                # regex to validate a float
                validate.regex(['lat', 'lon'], pattern='[+-]?(?=\d*[.eE])(?=\.?\d)\d*\.?\d*(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?')
            ))
       if errors:
            return response.redirect('/create-post').with_errors(errors)
```

The validator above allows me to submit an empty form (it shouldn't, but it doesn't seem to be performing the 'validate.exists' check), but if I enter data into each form field, the 'validate.regex' seems to work against the lat and lon data as it should.

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does however work. Check the form with validate.required first, and then if there are no errors, check it with validate.regex.

```
errors = request.validate(
            validate.required(['title', 'body', 'lat', 'lon']))
        if not errors:
            errors = request.validate(
                validate.regex(['lat', 'lon'], pattern='[+-]?(?=\d*[.eE])(?=\.?\d)\d*\.?\d*(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?'))
```